# Properly accessing observable value or passing a reference

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm kind of new to Angular and Typescript. I have a question regarding passing a reference into the subscribe function. So I have the code shown below... as you see I'm trying to assign user value from the observable, but it seems function doesn't see the reference. I've seen some other stackoverflow questions, but I don't know how to convert this to the pure arrow function nor how to get an instance of ProfileComponent to successufly asign the value.

I'm sorry, I'm very new to this stuff so I'd be very happy if someone could explain to me how to properly do this kind of stuff. Is there any alternative to observable, for ex. if you only one to fetch one item from a GET method, isn't it useless to fetch it as an observable?

Please Help.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../_services';
import { User } from '../_models';
import { userInfo } from 'os';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;

  constructor(userService: UserService) {
    this.user = new User();

    const obs$ = userService.getAll().subscribe({
      next(val) {
        console.log('Current object: ', val, '  user ', this.user);
        this.user.userId = val[0].userId;
        this.user.username = val[0].username;
     },
      error(msg) { console.log('Error Object: ', msg); }
      }
      );


    /*
    this.user.userId = obs[0].id;
    this.user.username = obs[0].username;
    this.user.password = obs[0].password;
    */
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply read the documentation? https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the context of `this` is being lost. Instead, try using arrow functions, like so:

```
const obs$ = userService.getAll().subscribe((val) => {
    console.log('Current object: ', val, '  user ', this.user);
    this.user.userId = val[0].userId;
    this.user.username = val[0].username;
 },
 (msg) => { console.log('Error Object: ', msg); });
```

This will ensure the context of `this` is retained